# Extend container into safe area - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an issue getting my container to extend downward into the "safe area" in my Flutter code.

Showing the problem. White container not extending to the edge of display:

[image]

```
return Card(
  elevation: 1,
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  child: SafeArea(
    top: false,
    bottom: true,
    minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        height: 50,
        width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0,0)
              )
            ],
          ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Row( [...]
```

Does anyone see what the issue might be, or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SafeArea` to extend the bottom, you should call `false`:

```
SafeArea(
    top: false,
    bottom: false,//<---- add this
    ...
)
```